# Call gstreamer through shared object library

Tags: gstreamer

I wrote a little gstreamer program under Ubuntu which takes a picture from my camera.
This works fine so far. Now I want this code to be in a shared library(.so) that can be called from Java(via JNA). But when executing my function, Java complains with 'undefined symbol: gst_init'.

For me it looks like that "gstreamer" is missing from my library.

I created the lib with pkg-config options: `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gtk+-3.0 gobject-introspection-1.0 tcam` for the compiler and `pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gtk+-3.0 gobject-introspection-1.0 tcam` for the linker.

Anybody with an idea how include gstreamer into a shared object library?

Comment: That will link GStreamer to your lib dynamically. That means it refers to the shared libraries of GStreamer. You will have to ship these as well.

Comment: What means "ship"? I'm working on one machine. The executable is working, the shared object is not. In both cases the GStreamer libs are present. Could it be, that I have to link GStreamer statically into my .so?

Comment: No. Check with the http://dependencywalker.com/ tool to check which DLLs it cannot find.

Comment: Mhm, dependency walker is for Windows only. As I said before I'm working with .so under Ubuntu (Linux). ldd <my lib> does not show any unresolved dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, missed that you are on Linux. Could it be that you linked with the `--as-needed` option? I think its default on modern compilers. E.g. is ldd output listing gstreamer as a library?

Comment: My linker options are:`pkg-config --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gtk+-3.0 gobject-introspection-1.0 tcam` -shared.

ldd is *not* showing gstreamer

Comment: So that may mean your shared library itself does not call gst_init() but only java does? Try `-Wl,--no-as-needed` as compiler flag for your library.

Comment: Java does not know about Gstreamer, my lib is calling gst_init().  `-Wl,--no-as-needed` doesn't changed a thing. My libs size doesn't change, ldd is not showing a dependency to gstreamer and my Java app is still missing gst_init().